# PHP / FB Graph: How do you access the message text from a message object?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm iterating over an array of `message` Nodes from my `messages` Graph Edge, and for some reason I cannot print the message of each `message` object. In the facebook Graph API reference [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/message), the field called `message` is what I need to get,and yet it's not printing anything. I have `read_page_mailboxes` permission checked. I checked the facebook page that I am retrieving messages from and it certainly does contain messages that I can print. I am able to print the `id` field of the message. How can I print the text of the message?

Here is the PHP code:

```
   $conversations = getFbResponse('page_id/conversations')->getGraphEdge(); //getFbResponse uses my access token and returns a response from Facebook to retrieve the graph edge or node
    foreach($conversations as $conversation){
        /*Grab the messages from the conversation*/
        $messages = getFbResponse($conversation->getField('id') . '/messages')->getGraphEdge();
    /*Here, im retrieving the individual messages from this conversation and printing the message text of the message*/
        foreach($messages as $message){
            echo $message->getField('message');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I need to request the fields of the node like so:

`getFbResponse('id_of_node' . '?fields=field1,field2...fieldN')->getGraphNode();` which will return a node with the specified fields accessible. From there I can call `getField('fieldName');` on the object and access the field I want.